# what does style="..." do?

Tags: css

I see this all the time and no matter how I try to search for it because it conflicts with so many other search strings like ellipsis and exact character match I can't get any search results explaining that this does. Sometimes I get woman's fashion and style or I get explanations on how to add ... at the end of text.

```
<div id="article_^article_id^" class="article" article-index="^article_index^">
    <h1>^article_headline^</h1>
    <h3 style="...">^article_subheading^</h3>
    <div class="article_body">
        ^tmp_elements=article=byline^
        <div class="timestamp" style="...">^article_timestamp^</div>
        ^article_layout^
    </div>
    ^comments^
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

I figured it out. I'm using WebStorm to look at this code I found on Github for pencilblue CMS. WebStorm is concatenating the variable that will be transliterated when the template in compiled.

After clicking on it for no reason it expanded to

```
<div id="article_^article_id^" class="article" article-index="^article_index^">
    <h1>^article_headline^</h1>
    <h3 style="^article_subheading_display^">^article_subheading^</h3>
    <div class="article_body">
        ^tmp_elements=article=byline^
        <div class="timestamp" style="^article_timestamp_display^">^article_timestamp^</div>
        ^article_layout^
    </div>
    ^comments^
    <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It does invaliate your html.

Comment: Check **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)**

Comment: where have you seen anything like this?

Comment: And you're sure it's not just a placeholder in explanatory texts?

Comment: `style="..."` does not typically appear in *CSS*. Since your question is only tagged [tag:css] without an actual code sample, this can be somewhat confusing. Please always provide a concrete sample what you're talking about.

Comment: WebStorm was just concatenating a variable placeholder to "...".

Comment: This is just webstorm collapsing it down for visual purposes, its not how the code is presented to the browser, just an IDE thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style rules for HTML can be added using:

1. External CSS Files
2. In-page Style Tags
3. Inline Style Attribute (<... Style="....")

An inline style may be used to apply a unique style for a single element.

An inline style loses many of the advantages of a style sheet (by mixing content with presentation). Use this method sparingly!

To use inline styles, add the style attribute to the relevant tag. The style attribute can contain any CSS property.

For example:-

```
<h3 style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">Hello Worlds</h3>
```

This will add `color:blue` and `margin-left:30px` CSS properties to your  element. Also note it will override any existing style applied to your element via external CSS file or Style tags. Since the priority goes as

1.Inline Style Attribute (<... Style="....")

2.In-page Style Tags

3.External CSS Files

[Reference link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about literal `...` in styles.

Answer (score -1):

Style (or Inline Style) is a property in HTML and HTML5 tags that is used to design and customize your HTML components, it's not different than a CSS file except that it is written inline with the HTML component. The following is an example of how to use the style inline property:

```
<input type="text" style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; background-color: #72a4d2;" size="10" maxlength="30">
```